# Can we freely switch back and forth between cycles and Blender Render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

If we switch between Blender Render and Cycles Render, do we "obscure" our project?

Or can we freely switch back and forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch however you like, but nodes from cycles won't work in internal at all... but you can switch it back to cycles and it will work as before

Comment: thanks but what are nodes? also while I'm here, can you tell me what the button is to show a kind of wire like view of our object?

Comment: @Pf22 Nodes are something you use in Cycles to create materials. If you press Z in viewport it should ask you what rendering mode you want. Those are pretty starter questions, check some tutorials